# Mapping elementwise Tuple Using Template Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, tuples

I am using `perform_mapping` from [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193420/apply-a-function-to-each-element-of-a-tuple-map-a-tuple) as here [link](https://godbolt.org/), but I get compilation Error.

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace details
{
    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type;
    
    template <template <typename ...> typename Tuple, typename ... Types, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type<Tuple<Types...>, Mapping>
    {
        //I changed the below line from what is in the link
        using type = Tuple<decltype(std::invoke_result<Mapping, Types>())...>;
    };
    template <template <typename, std::size_t> typename Array, typename T, std::size_t Size, typename Mapping>
    struct return_type<Array<T, Size>, Mapping>
    {
        using type = Array<std::invoke_result_t<Mapping, T>, Size>;
    };
    
    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping>
    using return_type_t = typename return_type<Tuple, Mapping>::type;
    
    template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping, std::size_t ... Indices>
    return_type_t<std::decay_t<Tuple>, std::decay_t<Mapping>> perform_mapping(Tuple&& tup, Mapping&& mapping, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    {
        return {mapping(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tup)))...};
    }
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Mapping, 
          std::size_t Size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>
auto perform_mapping(Tuple&& tup, Mapping&& mapping)
{
    return details::perform_mapping(std::forward<Tuple>(tup), std::forward<Mapping>(mapping), std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}

struct A
{
    A(double z) : x(z){}; 
    double x;
    using Type = double;
};

struct B
{
    B(std::string s) : x(std::move(s)) {}
    std::string x;
    using Type = std::string;
};

struct C
{
    C() : m_tuple({A(1.0), B("A")})
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    typename T::Type f(T& z)
    {
        return z.x;
    }

    std::tuple<A::Type, B::Type> get()
    {
        return perform_mapping(m_tuple, [this](auto& z) { return this->f(z); });
    }

    std::tuple<A, B> m_tuple;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    auto t = c.get();
};
```

My question is: Can I implement `perform_mapping` in a way the code above works?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ I changed the question

Comment: Please not my question I mention: //I changed the below line from what is in the link. I am not sure what to do after all this https://godbolt.org/ to make it work or understand the error

Comment: Now that the example is complete, this looks to be a good one. If I can figure it out, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and what is your question.

Comment: My question is how to map tuple using a template function. What I am trying to do is perfectly reflected in the question, the only difference is that my A and B are templated and hold a vector of the template parameter.

Comment: If I got your intent correctly, `perform_mapping()` is one-liner: `return std::apply([&](auto... vals){ return std::tuple(mapping(vals)...); }, tup);` (with some possible improvements to avoid copies).

Comment: Let me try that!!!

Comment: It actually works, not sure why people proposed ```perform_mapping``` in that thread. Thanks so much!

Comment: `std::apply` is a C++17 feature and the question you refer to has C++14 tag meaning that C++17 features can't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can benefit from [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), which together with a variadic lambda is a very handy tool to "unpack" a tuple:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename Mapping>
auto perform_mapping(const Tuple& tup, Mapping&& mapping)
{
    return std::apply([&](const auto&... vals) {
        return std::tuple(mapping(vals)...);
    }, tup);
}
```

(Perfect forwarding is left as an exercise.)